# Bitcoin Address Wiki Issue

Tags: address, bitcoin-wiki

I'm having issues following through the technical wiki here - https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_Bitcoin_addresses

Point 2 says to perform a SHA256 hash on the public key, which I'm understanding is "0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6"

When I try and perform a SHA256 hash on this using an online calculator such as http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator I get a hash of 32511e82d56dcea68eb774094e25bab0f8bdd9bc1eca1ceeda38c7a43aceddce

Can anyone explain to me why I'm getting a different hash to their example given? Am I assuming the wrong public key? Is it only meant to be a segment of that? Or does the wiki have a mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SHA256 hash tool you're using doesn't decode the hex into binary before hashing it. You can test that by passing in a string that isn't valid hex, like 'fhwdgads.' The wiki article assumes that you do that.

[This one will do what you want if you select the "Binary hash" option.](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm?hex=data)

Comment: Or from the shell: 
$ echo -n '01234567890ABCDEF' | xxd -r -p | sha256sum -b